# How to fill column with value taken from a (non-adjacent) previous row without natural partitioning key using Spark Scala DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input:

```
val input = Seq(
     |   ("1 February"),
     |   ("n"),
     |   ("c"),
     |   ("b"),
     |   ("2 February"),
     |   ("h"),
     |   ("w"),
     |   ("e"),
     |   ("3 February"),
     |   ("y"),
     |   ("s"),
     |   ("j")
     | ).toDF("lines")

input.show
```

The input looks like this:

```
+----------+
|     lines|
+----------+
|1 February|
|         n|
|         c|
|         b|
|2 February|
|         h|
|         w|
|         e|
|3 February|
|         y|
|         s|
|         j|
+----------+
```

Required output:

```
val output = Seq(
     |   ("1 February", "n"),
     |   ("1 February", "c"),
     |   ("1 February", "b"),
     |   ("2 February", "h"),
     |   ("2 February", "w"),
     |   ("2 February", "e"),
     |   ("3 February", "y"),
     |   ("3 February", "s"),
     |   ("3 February", "j")
     | ).toDF("date", "lines")

output.show
```

The output required looks like this:

```
+----------+-----+
|      date|lines|
+----------+-----+
|1 February|    n|
|1 February|    c|
|1 February|    b|
|2 February|    h|
|2 February|    w|
|2 February|    e|
|3 February|    y|
|3 February|    s|
|3 February|    j|
+----------+-----+
```

I'm thinking of using lag function in scala Spark dataframe, but really couldn't figure out after spending hours. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there always a constant number of letters (3) after a date or can it change?

Comment: Tricky as far as I can see.

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica  has there been improvement on the Monica affair?

Comment: Do you have a notion of ordering the data? It appears so, but with files??? May not be possible in fact to process reliably.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: jack I have an answer. have you progressed?

Comment: @thebluephantom Hi, I found a workaround, kind of hack. I created a column with index, then use pattern match to detect the "row id" of each "date". After that, create a column "Date", and set values based on the row number, the values are taken from the rows of those "row id" detected. Quite manual though

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica between each date, the number of rows is random, can be 4, 15, etc.

Comment: May be an idea to post an answer, but I do not really understand, mine is automatic. There are performance issues at scale as far as I can see.

Comment: Can u post your answer. I am checking one thing and will post it shortly. How many records per run?

Comment: @thebluephantom Sure, i will post it soon after I finish something on hands. :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @thebluephantom Speaking of performance, mine should be quite sht.. :-D

Comment: I will need to see, but seem my answer it is a typical issue. Posted it.

Comment: @thebluephantom: Well, there has been a legal settlement but all the details are secret. Monica has also left the network after that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stack-exchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with/342950#342950. So personally, I wouldn't say there has been any improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer I posted was correct but less distributed. From the .explain() we could observe `Exchange SinglePartition`.

This solution works in parallel - there is no SinglePartition to be found in the physical plan. At scale, it looks OK but the .explain becomes hard to read. It's a tall order if not wanting to think about it at all, so possibly not for everybody.

Due to obvious prevailing circumstances I could tackle it. It is also my last effort here on Data Wrangling as it is not worth a potential 15 + 10 points.  That said, my other answer also states the feed should be improved, which would be my professional advice. Hence this is a solution based on free time, but it highlights a few points and weaknesses. Assumption is that range partitioning is reliable, having checked with .glom it is indeed the case.

Too hard to explain, look at comments and conclusions.

**Code ran on Notebook:**

```
// May be academic. If low volume of data then my other solution can suffice, this is a distributed+ solution.
// Need 2 repartitions, interesting concept that turns out to be true.   
// Runs in parallel but the .explain hard to interprete.
// By extracting twice carefully from parent RDD, hoping that partition awareness is retained and that whole partiton moved to other executor with other partition so as to avoid hashing.
// Not certain if range Partitioning needs to check the ranges.
// Some educational coding aspects left in.

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lead, lag}
import spark.implicits._

// Gen example data via DF, can come from files, ordering in those files assumed. I.e. no need to sort.
val df = Seq(
 ("1 February"), ("n"), ("c"), ("b"), 
 ("2 February"), ("hh"), ("www"), ("e"), 
 ("3 February"), ("y"), ("s"), ("j"),
 ("1 March"), ("c"), ("b"), ("x"),
 ("1 March"), ("c"), ("b"), ("x"),
 ("2 March"), ("c"), ("b"), ("x"),
 ("3 March"), ("c"), ("b"), ("x"), ("y"), ("z")
 ).toDF("line")

// Define Case Classes to avoid Row aspects on df --> rdd --> to DF which I always must look up again.
case class X(line: String)
case class Xtra(key: Long, line: String)

// Add the Seq Num using zipWithIndex.
val rdd = df.as[X].rdd.zipWithIndex().map{case (v,k) => (k,v)}
val ds = rdd.toDF("key", "line").as[Xtra]

// An idea that was not totally utilized but left in.
val m = Map("january" -> 1,"february" -> 2,"march" -> 3, "april" -> 4)
val dfMth = m.toSeq.toDF("monthM", "monthNum")

// Num partitions for processing. 
// Apply Range Partititioning to allow subsequent distributed processing as opposed to Exchange SinglePartition.

val n = 5 // Can be altered, set here. This value drives parallel processing.
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5")

// Now records the partition the data is in. The issues is that there is no actual partitioning key and that the data of relevance can be in the next partition
// as well (at most one is the assumption made!), but we wish to have partitioned processing.
val rdd2 = ds.repartitionByRange(n, $"key")
   .rdd 
   .mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, iter) => {
      iter.map(x => (index, x ))   
    })
val df2 = rdd2.toDF("part", "line_data").cache

// Separate data into separate fields. 
val df3 = df2.withColumn("_tmp", split($"line_data.line", " "))
             .select($"part", $"line_data.key".as("key"),
                     $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("val"),
                     $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("month")
                    )
             .drop("_tmp")

// Data with partitioning and seq numbering and some tidy up of fields.
val df4 = df3.withColumn("val",   when(col("month").isNull, expr("substring(val,2,length(val)-2)")).otherwise(expr("substring(val,2,length(val))")))        
             .withColumn("month", expr("substring(month,1,length(month)-1)"))
val df44 = df4.withColumn("partX", $"part")

// Get first N rows per partition, N = 4 here, just an example.
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(df4.schema)
val df100 = df4.mapPartitions(iterator => iterator.take(4))
val df100U = df100.withColumn("partX", $"part" - 1)  
// Add 1st N rows of next partition to prior partition, except for last partition. Can be set higher if you think more data from previous entry spills over.
val dfC = df44.union(df100U)

// Repartition so that parallellization processing gives correct answer. Assuming Catalyst is partition aware. 
// Any other way means lose peformance. This is the parent RDD so we hope that Catalyst is smart enoygh.
val dfD = dfC.repartitionByRange(n, $"partX").cache() // Used twice.

// Get those values with a month entry that are the break points and get the adjacent values for comparison in next step.
val df55 = dfD.join(broadcast(dfMth), lower(dfD.col("month")) === dfMth.col("monthM")).drop("monthM").drop("monthNum")
@transient val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("partX").orderBy("key")  
val df555 = df55.withColumn("idxNextDate", (lead("key", 1, 999999999999L).over(w)-1)).toDF("part1", "key1", "val1", "month1", "partX", "idxNextDate").cache() 
// LKP table to be compared against with same range partition.

// Get the 'value' entries, not the month, date aspects.
val df66 = dfD.filter( $"month".isNull && $"partX" > -1)

// Make the calculation - in parallel, how well is not clear from DAG.
val dfZ = df66.join( df555, (df66("partX") === df555("partX")) 
                             && ($"key" geq $"key1") && ($"key" <= $"idxNextDate")
                             && ($"part1" === df555("partX")) 
                            && (df555("partX") =!= -1) )
              .select($"val1".alias("date"), $"month1".alias("month"), $"val".alias("lines"), $"key", df555("partX").alias("PX")).orderBy("PX", "key")//.explain()
dfZ.show(100)
```

As always you need to sort just to be safe with parallel processing, that is evident from the results - not shown here. But it depends on the use case. The sort process cannot see that the data is actually already sorted due to repartitioning and drawing from the same parent RDD and narrow transformation joins. I checked all this.

```
== Physical Plan ==
Sort [PX#2022 ASC NULLS FIRST, key#1758L ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0 
...
```

**returns:**

```
+----+--------+-----+---+---+
|date|   month|lines|key| PX|
+----+--------+-----+---+---+
|   1|February|    n|  1|  0|
|   1|February|    c|  2|  0|
|   1|February|    b|  3|  0|
|   2|February|   hh|  5|  0|
|   2|February|  www|  6|  0|
|   2|February|    e|  7|  0|
|   3|February|    y|  9|  1|
|   3|February|    s| 10|  1|
|   3|February|    j| 11|  1|
|   1|   March|    c| 13|  2|
|   1|   March|    b| 14|  2|
|   1|   March|    x| 15|  2|
|   1|   March|    c| 17|  2|
|   1|   March|    b| 18|  2|
|   1|   March|    x| 19|  2|
|   2|   March|    c| 21|  3|
|   2|   March|    b| 22|  3|
|   2|   March|    x| 23|  3|
|   3|   March|    c| 25|  4|
|   3|   March|    b| 26|  4|
|   3|   March|    x| 27|  4|
|   3|   March|    y| 28|  4|
|   3|   March|    z| 29|  4|
+----+--------+-----+---+---+
```

You should not need the sort, but the question is a little unclear if sorting is in fact required. Improve the feed I think.

Answer (score 1):

Scale of records and other things not clear.

Imho this is an example of a bad feed making life more difficult and challenging, and if at scale the situation is that of large table join with less large table join, something Spark not so good at. I am not sure of the best partitioning strategy as there are issues, but if you have large data you could split it out by month (, year). Or even by weeks and append to an output store.

You will need to concat fields, but here is a solution:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lead, lag}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Assume sorted input limited to a year? Unclear from the question. Volumes also not clear. Added some extra input.

val df = Seq(
    ("1 February"),
    ("n"),
    ("c"),
    ("b"),
    ("2 February"),
    ("h"),
    ("w"),
    ("e"),
    ("3 February"),
    ("y"),
    ("s"),
    ("j"),
    ("1 March"),
    ("c"),
    ("b"),
    ("x")
   ).toDF("line")

// Fill the other months in accordingly.
// Years aspect? Not considered.

val m = Map("january" -> 1,"february" -> 2,"march" -> 3, "april" -> 4)
val dfM = m.toSeq.toDF("month", "monthNum")
// monthNum not used in hindsight, but left in.

// Add a non-consecutive Sequence Nr. This not an issue as we use range checking later on, not a previous value of -1 relative to a Sequence Nr to check directly against.
// Partition position retained. The other option is .zipWithIndex with rdd conversion and back again to df. 
// monotonically_increasing_id is non-deterministic but it should be OK here as far as I can see.

val df2 = df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

val df3 = df2.withColumn("_tmp", split($"line", " "))
             .select($"idx",
                 $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),
                 $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2")
                    )
            .drop("_tmp")

val df4 = (df3.join(broadcast(dfM), lower(df3.col("col2")) === dfM.col("month")).drop("month")) 

val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("idx")  
val df5 = df4.withColumn("idxNextDate", (lead("idx", 1, 999999999999L).over(w)-1)).toDF("idx1","dte","mth", "mthNum", "idxNextDate")

// Not sure about performance, quite tricky, get large table / large table situation which has no real performance solution with Spark except for brute force parallelism.
// Could filter out the non-Null stuff.
val df6 = df3.filter($"col2".isNull)
val df7 = df6.join(df5, ($"idx" >= $"idx1") && ($"idx" <= $"idxNextDate"))
             .select($"dte", $"mth", $"col1".alias("lines"))
df7.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+--------+-----+
|dte|mth     |lines|
+---+--------+-----+
|1  |February|n    |
|1  |February|c    |
|1  |February|b    |
|2  |February|h    |
|2  |February|w    |
|2  |February|e    |
|3  |February|y    |
|3  |February|s    |
|3  |February|j    |
|1  |March   |c    |
|1  |March   |b    |
|1  |March   |x    |
+---+--------+-----+
```

I will think about the partitioning, but it seems hard in this algorithm to decide on a suitable strategy. I am not convinced it is elegantly possible to partition, this is a good example of processing that does not fit nicely with Spark processing style. I may stand corrected though.

**UPDATE**
Cannot find suitable partitioning. Need to process small sets therefore.

> Recommendation in this case is to adapt the feed so as to make things
>   trivial as opposed to setting people to work to tackle an issue like
>   this.

**UPDATE 2** 
Found a creative parallel approach, need to think whether to post or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm posting my solution, it's not beautiful but it temporarily solve my problem.

Comment: log generated by programs usually has better format, but e.g. event timeline from wiki or some web can have this kind of format, 1st line: 1 Feburary, 2nd line: event1, 3rd line: event2 etc.

Comment: Think I have another smarter solution, but will see if I have time to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
val input1 = input.withColumn("RowId", monotonicallyIncreasingId).withColumn("Date", col("lines"))
val len = udf((str: String) => str.size)
val rowIds = input1.filter(len(col("lines")) < 13 && len(col("lines")) > 4).select("RowId").collect.map(_(0)).map(_.toString.toInt)
val rowIdSlided = (rowIds :+ input.count).sliding(2).toList
val output = rowIdSlided.foldLeft(input1)((acc, rowIdList) => {acc.withColumn("Date", when((col("RowId") > rowIdList(0) && col("RowId") < rowIdList(1)), ({val date = input1.filter(col("RowId") === rowIdList(0)).select("lines").collect.map(_(0)).map(_.toString); date(0)})).otherwise(col("Date")))}).drop("RowId")
```

This should give the output:

```
+----------+----------+
|     lines|      Date|
+----------+----------+
|1 February|1 February|
|         n|1 February|
|         c|1 February|
|         b|1 February|
|2 February|2 February|
|         h|2 February|
|         w|2 February|
|         e|2 February|
|3 February|3 February|
|         y|3 February|
|         s|3 February|
|         j|3 February|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: partition boundaries? I will try tomorrow

Comment: toList also not a Big Data approach, sorry.

Comment: OK, I see you can work with Scala well, but aspects do not run in parallel due to collect and List, so it is not a suitable solution at scale. In fact as I state, the feed if improved means we do not need to do any of this.

Comment: thanks actually for the comment about collect and toList and partition boundaries, i need to learn about that :)

Comment: I have a solution that is scalable as well witha  little trickery. I will post this weekend.

Comment: I have a parallel approach answer, it's a lot of work so I have to tidy it up.